# Perform multiple tasks from a single sharepoint list form with client-side js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, client-side

I have three separate SP apps on the same site...
SP List - "Document Tracker"
SP Document Library - "Documents"
SP Task List - "Tasks"

Here is the concept...
User creates a new list item in "Document Tracker" new item form in addition to saving a file to "Documents", and create one or more new items in the "Tasks" list; however, after the user creates a new task or save the document they need to return to the form to save the information the Document Tracker list.

What I have tried...
For the new Task item - js Link in a CEWP on the form webpart with a JavaScript example from MSDN, but I lose the information already in the form.

For the document library - onClick event with the new document url....works, but again I lose the information already in the form.

Am  I trying to do too much from the form..or is there a way to get this done?